# Is it good or bad for humans and for the development of human society to hide their facial emotional expressions from strangers?

Tags: society, creature-design, humans

I am working on a story. I just want to know, will it be good for humans and for the development of human society to hide their facial emotional expressions from others especially strangers?

If that's good, please provide the points on how far a human should avoid show their emotions? I mean should that boundary of expressing has to be just with their family?

And if that's bad then please provide why it's bad?

Well I feel that a person could also be judged as whether he is weak or strong on seeing his facial expressions. So I feel its better to hide their expression based on the above point.

Let's just consider that the background of my story has fantasy characters living along with humans. And while answering please also add points not just about facial expressions but also on expressing a persons emotions.

Comment: Strip out the story bits, and ask psychology the basics: "is it good for humans to hide their emotions from other people, or is it bad?"

Comment: A little thought, though, should tell you that there are times when we want to show emotion, and times when we need to/should hide our emotions.

Comment: Just as a tip: cross-site duplicates are often an indicator that a question is not given enough thought, because if you can copy-paste it from one site to the next then there probably aren't any specific details for one of the sites. For future questions: If you would like some feedback before posting on the main site you can check out our [Sandbox on Meta](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/109257/28789)

Comment: I just realized I posted the wrong link. Here is the *real* link to [the Sandbox on Meta](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4835/sandbox-for-proposed-questions)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it will help. Emotions is something all humans share.
You tend to like people more when you realise they're just a human like you.
However if a stranger doesn't show emotions it's really hard to build a bond.

Comment: Building bonds is also mediated by culture. In a culture where not showing emotions is normal behaviour, showing emotions will be deviant and won't lead to bonding. Western culture emphasizes displays of emotions for bonding and amiability.

Answer (score 0):

From an evolutionary point of view, humans specifically developed facial muscles to express their emotions, in order to further understanding between fellow humans and build societies because working together helped the human race to survive. So I'd say, it's not beneficial if you want a society where people help each other out and work together well.

However, cultures might develop different behaviours for reasons that make perfect sense in their specific circumstances, and then these behaviours will be given cultural significance and a valid explanation, which will influence the thinking of future generations and make them biased towards thinking something is beneficial when it no longer is - or the other way round.

So I think it is not beneficial for the human race as a whole, but it might be beneficial for smaller units of it. Maybe it would be beneficial if humans were not the only intelligent species and the others were the "strangers" you referred to. But probably not beneficial enough that it would develop as an evolutionary trait, and if you remain with a cultural explanation then you can always justify it with cultural values.